# HTTP/XML Binding with Spring Web services

Tags: web-services, http, spring-ws

I am working on web services POC. I need to develop a Spring-based web services, that use XML/HTTP i.e. [HTTP binding](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_http) (NOT SOAP/HTTP) so that I can invoke a web-service with URL parameters like the one example described in the WSDL [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_http-e) especially a GET with query parameters.

I am unable to map the URL's query-parameter to the end-point's (@EndPoint) method parameter.

Is it possible to develop such a web-service (XML/HTTP bound) with spring-ws? 
Is it possible to invoke such a service with GET request + query string?

Let me know for any such examples/tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at this page (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch18s02.html).  Assuming that you are using spring 3, I believe you should find some relief there.

Based your question, I assume you already have the DispatcherServlet declared and mapped in web.xml.  The trick, then, is to pull out the arguments.  The page indicates how to pull arguments from both the URL (which I believe is your goal) and from the request body.

Good luck and write back if anything is unclear.

Comment: I am using Spring-3.1.What you suggest is RESTful service, different from a Web-service with HTTP binding.Is it not? I dont think that a WSDL can be generated for a RESTful service.

Comment: The documentation uses the context of a restful service, although restful as a concept is more about how a service works from an architectural standpoint.  I believe you can achieve a service which complies with HTTP/XML wsdl as described in the spec using the 'restful' machinery (although I do not know that spring will help with an auto-generated WSDL).

Comment: I believe if we develop a 'restful' service, what we can get is a WADL (that too not dynamic with Spring) and not a WSDL.

Comment: That may be the case.  I have more experience with creating soap-based spring services and am familiar with the WSDL which is constructed around the schema objects.  Even then it is possible to override with a static WSDL.  If a WSDL is required for your use case, it is *possible* that a static WSDL could be provided in place of a WADL, but I cannot say for certain.  Good luck with the project.