# How can I convert a .NET web service to Spring WS based web service?

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, spring, web-services

I need to convert my ASP.NET web service (.asmx) to Java using Spring framework with multiple bindings, in other words, I should be able to access my web service using SOAP and simple HTTP GET/POST also. I have created a simple web service using Spring however it does not support simple POST/GET request. Any pointers in this direction ? Thanks.

Comment: forget java. what do you want that for? if anything, host your .Net code in Mono.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP/XML Binding with Spring Web services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574352/http-xml-binding-with-spring-web-services)

Comment: This does not covers the scenario I have, it just covers HTTP GET/POST, I need to have capability for both SOAP POST and plain HTTP GET/POST

Answer (score 1):

Use Spring REST webservice.It supports HTTP post/get requests.
Visit https://spring.io/understanding/REST

Comment: I need to have capability for both SOAP POST and plain HTTP GET/POST so this does not solve my problem.